# change event on form - only fires on first set of radio buttons, not the rest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To keep listeners to a minimum, I am using one `change` listener on form. However, the event only fires if I change the first column/set of radio buttons. It does not fired on the rest of the columns of radio buttons.

Why is this and how would it be possible to use just one change listener for all radio buttons?

```
<div class="filter-column" data-ng-init="init()">
  <form name="ppvSelectionForm">
    <div class="filter-title">Region</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <input type="radio" value="all" name="regionRadio" checked>All
      <div ng-repeat="choice in regions| orderBy: 'description'">
        <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="regionRadio">
        {{choice.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Market</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-if="markets.length >= 1">
        <input type="radio" value="all" name="marketRadio" checked>All
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="choice in markets| orderBy: 'name'">
        <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="marketRadio">
        {{choice.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Dealer</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-if="dealers.length >= 1">
        <input type="radio" value="all" name="dealerRadio" checked>All
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="choice in dealers| orderBy: 'name'">
        <input type="radio" value="{{choice.name}}" name="dealerRadio">
        {{choice.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
 $scope.init = function() {
    formEl = document.querySelector('form[name="ppvSelectionForm"]');
    formEl.addEventListener("change", radioMap);
  } 

  function radioMap(el) {
    console.log(el.target.name)
    switch(el.target.name) {
      case 'regionRadio':
        regionsOrMarkets(el.target.value);
      break;
      case 'marketRadio':
        populateDealers(el.target.value);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you saying `change` for radio button `value="all"`  works and not the ones from ng-repeat ?

Comment: It will fire the event for ANY of the first set of radio buttons with `name="regionRadio"`. The other sets will not fire the event when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this seems to be the culprit from the snippet provided. The extra closing div is closing the scope of the Controller.

```
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="filter-column" data-ng-init="init()">
      <form name="ppvSelectionForm">
        <div class="filter-title">Region</div>
        <div class="bottom-line"></div>
        <div class="overflow-container">
          <input type="radio" value="all" name="regionRadio" checked>All
          <div ng-repeat="choice in regions">
            <input type="radio" value="{{choice}}" name="regionRadio">
            {{choice}}
          </div>
        </div>
     </div><------ Extra closing div
```

Let me know if this helps. tried it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LggLye7j/2/)